# Que significa, y utilidad de: <!-- --> en JS

Tags: javascript

Recientemente e visto un código en JS que posee estos caracteres

```
<script>
<!--
function filterFloat(evt,input){
    // Backspace = 8, Enter = 13, ‘0′ = 48, ‘9′ = 57, ‘.’ = 46, ‘-’ = 43
    var key = window.Event ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;    
    var chark = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var tempValue = input.value+chark;
    if(key >= 48 && key <= 57){
        if(filter(tempValue)=== false){
            return false;
        }else{       
            return true;
        }
    }else{
          if(key == 8 || key == 13 || key == 0) {     
              return true;              
          }else if(key == 46){
                if(filter(tempValue)=== false){
                    return false;
                }else{       
                    return true;
                }
          }else{
              return false;
          }
    }
}
function filter(__val__){
    var preg = /^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,2})$/; 
    if(preg.test(__val__) === true){
        return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
    
}
-->
</script>



<input type="text" id="decimal" value="0" onkeypress="return filterFloat(event,this);">
```

el script es para el uso máximo 2 decimales permitiendo un solo punto (500.10) en un input

se que estos se usan para comentar código en HTML pero nunca los había visto en un script
y desearía saber que son y si posee alguna utilidad?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el script completo para tener más contexto?

Comment: Hablando estrictamente de JS, eso produce un error, y no tiene ningún sentido o utilidad.

Comment: No produce ningún error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa sintaxis es para archivos HTML, XML, en Javascript te ocasionaría un error

Comment: No, mira el código que e agregado y pruébalo, a mi no me genera ningún error

Comment: esa sintaxis esta incorrecta, dentro del tag script solo debe ir codigo javascript [ver](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp)

Comment: Si eso pensé al principio que esto generaría un error, pero e probado el código y no me a saltado ningún ninguno

Comment: Te dejo esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/808850/16707181) donde pone en contexto porque los navegadores no lo marcan como un error.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Como es una mala practica y ya no se usa procedo a eliminar esta pregunta